# Sqlite's reader.getstring function not letting me assign to a variable

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHnuF.png

Here is a screenshot of what is happening.

If I print the getstring to the console it will come out but I can't assign it to the structured array aItem(index).name because of an unhandled nullreferenceexception

Can anyone explain what is happening? GetString should be returning a string, no?

Comment: Which object is null when you hover over it? The Array variable or the reader?

Comment: You simply haven't created the array.  You have to specify the size of an array to create one.  Where have you specified the size of `aItem`?

Comment: I have it created as a dynamic array at the beginning of the class
http://i.imgur.com/Z17JJdt.png

Comment: Doh! I forgot to ReDim, I'm actually updating an old program to use sqlite and missed a line of code that I used when I ran into this problem last time around. 

I think I found out that the problem was that a structured array cannot be dynamic so everytime I ran a new input I used ReDim Preserve aItem(index) after the index was updated from the last run.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may run into the same error in the future,

Since the array I am using is a structure I can't have it be a dynamic array, to solve the problem I ReDim every time I get passed the check to see if there is another row of data for me to use

`ReDim preserve aItem(index)`

with index being updated everytime the block of code runs, this stops aItem from becoming null while it is still pulling data from the database.